# Calculate Hourly Pay Based on Pay Rate Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to calculate the hourly pay based on the pay rate column. Technically, I am trying to see who has hourly pay assigned to that column vs folks that have annual salary in that column.

| Employee | Pay_Rate |
| --- | --- |
| 400001 | 10283.52 |
| 304068 | 120000 |
| 304069 | 20.25 |

I am trying to find a decimal and if decimal is found, I seeing if its greater than zero. If its greater than zero, then I leaving it alone assuming its hourly pay; but if decimal isnt found, then I am taking that number and dividing by 2080 to get hourly pay. My logic, however, works well unless there is a decimal in annual pay. How do I code around that?

```
CASE WHEN ((EMP.PAY_RATE - trunc(EMP.PAY_RATE)) > 0) THEN EMP.PAY_RATE ELSE (EMP.PAY_RATE/2080) END AS "Hourly_Wage",
```

Sample output from the abve data set is:

| Payrate |
| --- |
| 10283.52 |
| 57.692307 |
| 20.25 |

Comment: This is absolutely weird. You have payment amounts stored in a table, but you don't know what that amount means? Whether it's hourly or yearly? Why is this information not stored in the table? And you think a good indicator is whether there are decimals in the number? Wouldn't the amount itself be a better indicator? 20.25 is probably not the  anual salary and 120000 not the hourly. This has nothing to do with decimals, it is because 120000 would be a lot for an hour and 20.25 very little for a year. So change your rule, find a threshold and you're done.

Comment: You don't need Oracle's programming language PL/SQL for this. This is SQL only. I've changed the tags accordingly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - thats a great suggestion. I was probably over thinking. I change the logic to see if the pay rate was less than, say, $600 then used the pay rate information else did the math to get the pay rate.

Answer (score 0):

Simply changed the pay rate threshold. I was over thinking this until I read the comment from Thorsten.

```
CASE WHEN (EMP.PAY_RATE < 600) THEN EMP.PAY_RATE ELSE (EMP.PAY_RATE/2080) END AS "Hourly_Wage"
```